# Android NavigationDrawer and Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

Help me please to create `Toolbar`, which content will be over `@+id/left_drawer`? Is it possible?
[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        style="@style/MainTheme.ToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.astuetz.RobottoRegularTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.astuetz.RobottoLightTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!--ImageView for test -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hata was very close to the correct answer. U need to put `Toolbar` after `DrawerLayout`, make `Toolbar`'s background transparent and create form before `@+id/content_frame` in `DrawerLayout` which height will be `?attr/actionBarSize` with background color as Toolbar was. here is my solution for U

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.kpi.timetable.views.HackyDrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/YOUR_ACTIONBAR_COLOR"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </com.kpi.timetable.views.HackyDrawerLayout>

    <!-- in your MainTheme.ToolBar style set background       -->
    <!-- color to "@android:color/transparent" or set it here -->
    <!-- as android:background="@android:color/transparent"   -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        style="@style/MainTheme.ToolBar"            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.astuetz.RobottoRegularTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Расписание"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.astuetz.RobottoLightTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the parent LinearLayout, the Toolbar may be placed at first and the DrawerLayout may be placed at second.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        style="@style/MainTheme.ToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    (...)

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Navigation Drawer.

I recommend you to visit Android documentation

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

In that case, your code will be

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        style="@style/MainTheme.ToolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.astuetz.RobottoRegularTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.astuetz.RobottoLightTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It's a simple drawer realization. Loock at picture that I were uploaded. There are full screen height menu (in your case listView) which after swiping comes from left border and toolbar's content is over it. Maybe toolbar's bg make transparent, but i don't know how to make it's content over menu (